# mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I got tasked to help speed up this query and I think some of the indexes on these tables are not setup properly.  I also believe they're not all going to be used b/c a function is applied to the col that I have an index on. can anyone see how I can optimize these tables or query?   The `requests` table will be the largest table of the 3 and will have upwards of 200k+ records. `devices` currently is sitting ~500 records and `clients` will be smaller as well.

Query:

```
explain extended SELECT MAX(Request.datetime) AS datetime, Device.id,
       Device.client_id, Device.mac_address, Device.type, Device.manufacturer,
       Device.model_number, Client.id, Client.email_address,
       Request.device_id, Request.datetime, Request.ip_address
  FROM livefi.devices AS Device
  LEFT JOIN livefi.clients AS Client
    ON (Client.id         = Device.client_id)
 INNER JOIN livefi.requests AS Request
    ON (Request.device_id = Device.id)
 GROUP BY Request.device_id, Request.client_id

+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                                           | key           | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Device  | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                 | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                    |  617 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Client  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY       | 4       | livefi.Device.client_id |    1 |   100.00 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Request | ref    | idx_device_id,inx_requests_deviceId_datetime_ip_address | idx_device_id | 5       | livefi.Device.id        |  144 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac_address` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_address` (`email_address`),
  KEY `idx_mac_address` (`mac_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac_address` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mac_address` (`mac_address`),
  KEY `idx_mac_address` (`mac_address`),
  KEY `fk_devices_clients1` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_devices_clients1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=492 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `requests` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gmt_offset` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_method` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` text,
  `http_protocol` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `http_status_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_size` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `referer` text,
  `user_agent` text,
  `squid_cache_response` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `idx_datetime` (`datetime`),
  KEY `idx_device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `idx_domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `idx_id` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_request_size` (`request_size`),
  KEY `inx_requests_deviceId_datetime_ip_address` (`device_id`,`datetime`,`ip_address`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_requests_clients` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_requests_devices1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_requests_domains1` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domains` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200523 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX (device_id, client_id, datetime);
```

Also, please note you shouldn't include `Request.datetime` nor `Request.ip_address` in your `SELECT` clause, because they are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause. This is because several rows in `requests` may have the same `device_id` and `client_id`, and which value is picked for `datetime` or `ip_address` is somewhat random.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an index on Devices on ( Device_ID, ID ) and I've offered this in the past and has apparently worked great for the other person.  Dates can be a bit of a bottleneck in queries, but integers are easy.

IF you take a pre-query of just Device AND MAX(ID), this will in essence RETURN the latest date/time... Since the ID is auto-incremented, its date/time value will directly correlate as the most recent.. so they are one-in-the-same.

An exception would be if you were in some sort of clustered environment of multipler servers possibly adding their own auto-inc ID column that could cause a false max entry.  If this is the case, then change the index to (Device_ID, DateTime).

That said, I would then do the following

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      PerQuery.Device_ID,
      PreQuery.LastRequestID as Request_ID,
      RDtl.datetime, 
      d.client_id, 
      d.mac_address, 
      d.type, 
      d.manufacturer,
      d.model_number, 
      c.id, 
      c.email_address,
      r.ip_address
   FROM 
      ( select rq.Device_ID,
               MAX( rq.ID ) as LastRequestID
            from
               livefi.Requests rq
            group by
               rq.Device_ID ) PreQuery
         JOIN livefi.Request RDtl
            ON PreQuery.LastRequestID = RDtl.ID
            JOIN livefi.Clients c
               ON RDtl.ClientID = c.ID
         JOIN livefi.Devices d
               ON PreQuery.Device_ID = d.ID
```

The prequery is the only one with the group by and would be optimized directly to the index...  Since each device will only return one record and its corresponding "Request" ID, that will just join to the original request table for the "other" details, client and device details.